# Begin Align - Text Gaps

Tags: align

I have a quick question about blocks of the following type:

```
\begin{align*}
CODE HERE
\end{align*}
```

After any one of these blocks I always get this huge gap.  In the uncompiled document I have one space between a block like this and another paragraph, but when compiled it leaves about half a page of space.  Is there a quick fix to this issue that still leaves all the formatting in the block (and ideally in the rest of the document) the same, without the gaps?

Edit:

I am now in fact having another issue where blocks like this

```
\begin{align*}                                                                      
          a&=b                 
          &=b                                    
          &=b                                         
          &=b                                  
          &=b              
          &=b                                                           
          \end{align*}
```

Are not being read in vertically, and instead are being read across the page in a very awkward way.  Is this a problem with align or is more code needed to decide?

Comment: Don't use spaces or empty lines above and below (except if you want a new paragraph after it) this kind of environment. Also, the vertical justification depends on the total content of the page.

Comment: Please _always_ post a complete small document that shows the issue. It is very hard to comment on a fragment.

Comment: @Sigur I see what you mean.  That actually resolved the issue, as I didn't want a new paragraph, but is there a way then to include a space and have less of a gap?  My issue is that if I wanted to start a new paragraph then I would likely include a space, but doing so would still lead to this massive gap.

Comment: @user33916 there is by default no massive gap before or after `align` so if you are getting that it is because TeX can not find a good page break due to other things on the page, or the position of this align on the page (which is the same thing really). So it just depends on code you have not shown.

Comment: You have no line breaks ` \\ `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing that your document looks like this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
%\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}


zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz 
zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz 
zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz 
zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz zz 

\vspace{11cm}

aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
\begin{align*}
a&b\\a&b\\a&bb\\aaa&b\\a&bbbb\\a&b\\aaa&bbb\\a&b\\a&bbbb\\aaaa&b
\end{align*}
cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc
cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc 
cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc cccc 

\end{document}
```

In which case a possible solution is to allow page breaks with the display (uncomment `\allowdisplaybreaks` and you get:

[image]

Comment: That's essentially correct.  I'll edit my post to include some relevant code.  It seems I'm having a lot of issues with this alignment code since it also prevents me from writing comments row by row.   Apologies for the delay I was having some issues with my internet, I had hoped to post this sooner.

Answer (score 1):

You have no line breaks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}                                                                      
  a&=b\\                 
  &=b\\                                    
  &=b\\                                         
  &=b\\                                  
  &=b\\              
  &=b                                                           
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Do you see the difference between my block of code and yours (below)?

```
\begin{align*}                                                                      
      a&=b                 
      &=b                                    
      &=b                                         
      &=b                                  
      &=b              
      &=b                                                           
      \end{align*}
```

After each line, I have `\\` which then starts a new line that is aligned at the equal sign.

Comment: @user33916 that isn't how the site works.  If another users finds this thread and has the same issue, how is he/she going to find and solve their problems without creating a duplicate post?

Comment: That's fair.  How about I give you replacement code that shows the same difference?

Comment: @user33916 even if I remove it, it still can be found.  Go to your post and you will see `edited 8 mins ago`.  If you click on it, you will see your deleted code is still viewable to all.

Comment: I see what you mean, that's alright then.  Thanks for editing though!